# laravel - Updating relation with many 'childs'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this database:
parents

```
| id |  name  |  
+----+--------+  
|  1 |  Paul  |  
|  2 |  Annet |
```

childs

```
| id |    name   |  
+----+-----------+  
|  1 |  Micheal  |  
|  2 |   Susan   |
```

and pivot table `parents_childs`

```
| parent_id | child_id | custom_field_1 | custom_field_2 |  
+-----------+----------+----------------+----------------+  
|     1     |     1    |    value_1     |      (null)    |  
|     2     |     1    |  value_another |     value_3    |
```

and standard relation `belongsToMany`

```
public function parents(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Parent', 'parents_childs', 'child_id', 'parent_id')
                ->withPivot(
                    'custom_field_1',
                    'custom_field_2'
                );
}
```

Now I need to update pivot fields of specified child but only for one parent, eg.

```
SET red_value FOR custom_field_2 WHERE child_id = 1 AND parent_id = 2
```

How can I do this without QueryBuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships):

> If you need to update an existing row in your pivot table, you may use `updateExistingPivot` method. This method accepts the pivot record foreign key and an array of attributes to update:

```
$child = Child::find($childId);
$child->parents()->updateExistingPivot($parentId, ['custom_field_2' => 'red_value']);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships